# How to speed up on starting line in Sonic Rivals?

Tags: sonic-rivals

I get that I need to press X while holding the down button but it often just make me roll a bit forward then slow down a second later and roll in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build up a faster boost on the starting line, you should be pressing X pretty rapidly while holding down.

This isn't explained that well in-game - I think Sonic Rivals just assumes that you're familiar with "revving" your spindash in the original games.

Comment: Thanks! They really should've made that clearer. I haven't played any Sonic games prior.